# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in Hive and how to manage this format date?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, format

I have a column which has dates in the format dd-mm-yyyy. Can I storage into table with 'date' type?

I know that it could be storage with string/varchar type, but is this the only way to storage it?

How can I manage different date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive supports the date datatype, but it needs to be stored in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. So in order for you to store a date datatype you need to convert it to that format.

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01-01-2099','dd-MM-yyyy')))
```